# Run javascript datepicker in RStudio

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to include a javascript datepicker in Shiny app. However, I don't know how to import and/or run the code in R.
Here is the source: http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/

I would ideally like to include this code in ui.R.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Shiny comes with a date picker input:

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  dateInput("date1", "Date:", value = "2012-02-29"),

  # Default value is the date in client's time zone
  dateInput("date2", "Date:"),

  # value is always yyyy-mm-dd, even if the display format is different
  dateInput("date3", "Date:", value = "2012-02-29", format = "mm/dd/yy"),

  # Pass in a Date object
  dateInput("date4", "Date:", value = Sys.Date()-10),

  # Use different language and different first day of week
  dateInput("date5", "Date:",
            language = "ru",
            weekstart = 1),

  # Start with decade view instead of default month view
  dateInput("date6", "Date:",
            startview = "decade")
)

shinyApp(ui, server = function(input, output) { })
```

Demo: http://shiny.rstudio.com/gallery/date-selector.html

If that is not enough you can always build your own input object: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/building-inputs.html